# как использовать библиотеку рандом ? в discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, случайные-числа, discord.py

я хочу сделать команду для дискорд бота.
при написании .рандом 1 6 (выдавалось рандомное число)

```
import random
    
@bot.command(aliases = ['рандом'])
    async def random(ctx,*, arg1,):
        await ctx.send( random.choice(arg1))
```

но что то идет не по плану и выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я понимаю что ему не нравится choice но в документации такое есть

Comment: Так в вашем коде random - это не библиотека, а функция, которую создали вы сами. И в вашей функции нету никакого choice, разумеется

Comment: import random я это писал

Comment: А потом вы написали `async def random` и таким образом уничтожили библиотеку

Comment: спасибо помогло )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['рандом'])
async def randoms(ctx,*, arg1,):
    await ctx.send( random.choice(arg1))
```

вдруг кому понадобится (это рабочий код)

Comment: Если надо, вы можете в алиасах указать имя `random` - `aliases = ['рандом', 'random']`